# Add custom input outside the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In admin/some_item.rb form is rendered. I don't know how to add my custom input so that it wouldn't submit with that form.

I found a lot of suggestions like 'use render' or 'use content do' - in both cases exception was thrown: undefined method render/content

admin/some_item.rb

```
...
form do |f|
  inputs 'some name' do
    input :name
    input: amount
  end
  actions
end
```

//here i want to add my input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to add a second form beneath the default form that ActiveAdmin creates. To do this, you'll want to take complete control of how the form should render and behave.

You'll want to render the form using a *partial*, and insert a second form beneath the default one:

```rb
# admin/some_item.rb
form partial: 'form'
```

```
<!-- views/admin/some_item/_form.html.erb -->

<!-- This will be the default form that posts to the path ActiveAdmin expects -->
= semantic_form_for [:admin, @some_item], builder: ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder do |f|
  = f.inputs "Details" do
    = f.input :name
    = f.input :amount
    = f.actions

<!-- Add any number of additional forms with custom end-points. -->
<!-- You'll need to set up the end-points yourself. -->
```

Here's the relevant official documentation: https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html#partials

The second form will probably be submitting to a custom active admin action - the documentation for this can be found here: https://activeadmin.info/8-custom-actions.html